# Incorrectly Replacing Content

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace the term brunch in only sentences that contain any of the following words: saturday, sunday and/or weekend. However, it is replacing the entire sentence rather than just the term brunch.

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?:(?:^|\.)[^.]*(?=saturday|sunday|weekend)[^.]*(brunch)[^.]*(?:\$|\.)|(?:^|\.)[^.]*(brunch)[^.]*(?=saturday|sunday|weekend)[^.]*(?:\$|\.))',re.I)
>>> str = 'Limit 1 per person. Limit 1 per table. Not valid for carryout. Not valid 
    with any other offers, no cash back. Valid only for Wednesday-Friday dinner and 
    Saturday-Sunday brunch. Not valid on federal holidays. Reservation required.'
>>> reg.findall(str)
[('brunch', '')]
>>> reg.sub(r'BRUNCH',str)
'Limit 1 per person. Limit 1 per table. Not valid for carryout. Not valid with any 
 other offers, no cash backBRUNCH Not valid on federal holidays. Reservation required.'
```

I want it to produce the following:

```
Limit 1 per person. Limit 1 per table. Not valid for carryout. Not valid with any other
offers, no cash back. Valid only for Wednesday-Friday dinner and Saturday-Sunday BRUNCH. 
Not valid on federal holidays. Reservation required.
```

Answer:

To solve this I was able to use the following:

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?:((?:^|\.)[^.]*(?=saturday|sunday|weekend)[^.]*)(brunch)([^.]*(?:\$|\.))|((?:^|\.)[^.]*)(brunch)([^.]*(?=saturday|sunday|weekend)[^.]*(?:\$|\.)))',re.I)
>>> reg.sub('\g<1>BRUNCH\g<3>',str)
'Limit 1 per person. Limit 1 per table. Not valid for carryout. Not valid with any other offers, no cash back. Valid only for Wednesday-Friday dinner and Saturday-Sunday BRUNCH. Not valid on federal holidays. Reservation required.'
```

Comment: You need to store rest of the sentence too and back reference them in replacement string.

Comment: btw it's best to not call your variable `str` because that overwrites a builtin function.

Comment: Good point on str, its just in this demo though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're forced to use regex:

Search for

```
((?:^|\.)(?=[^.]*(?:saturday|sunday|weekend))[^.]*)brunch
```

replace with

```
\1BRUNCH
```

Make sure you compile it as case-insensitive. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP1bD1/2).

Note that this only replaces one occurence of `brunch` per sentence.

Comment: I slightly edited this to complete it: >>> reg = re.compile(r'(?:((?:^|\.)[^.]*(?=saturday|sunday|weekend)[^.]*)(brunch)([^.]*(?:\$|\.))|((?:^|\.)[^.]*)(brunch)([^.]*(?=saturday|sunday|weekend)[^.]*(?:\$|\.)))',re.I)
>>> reg.sub('\g<1>BRUNCH\g<3>',str)
'Limit 1 per person. Limit 1 per table. Not valid for carryout. Not valid with any other offers, no cash back. Valid only for Wednesday-Friday dinner and Saturday-Sunday BRUNCH. Not valid on federal holidays. Reservation required.'

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a regex, it's simpler to break it down into steps:

```
s = "Limit 1 per person. Limit 1 per table. Not valid for carryout. Not valid with any other offers, no cash back. Valid only for Wednesday-Friday dinner and Saturday-Sunday brunch. Not valid on federal holidays. Reservation required."
results = []
for line in s.split("."):
    if any(text in line.lower() for text in ("saturday", "sunday", "weekend")):
        results.append(line.replace("brunch", "BRUNCH"))
    else:
        results.append(line)
result = ".".join(results)
print(result)
```

Comment: Additional advantage: unlike regex, this will replace multiple occurences of `brunch` in a sentence.

Comment: This would normally work, except in this particular instance it is used as input for another function which requires a regex and a substitution.

Comment: I'm not following. It produces the desired input; is there more to the problem than was described in the question? Please update the question to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your regex simple like this and use a back-reference in replacement:

```
reg = re.compile(r'((?:saturday|sunday|weekend)\s+)brunch', re.I)
reg.sub(r'\1BRUNCH',str)
'Limit 1 per person. Limit 1 per table. Not valid for carryout. Not valid with any other
 offers, no cash back. Valid only for Wednesday-Friday dinner and Saturday-Sunday BRUNCH.
 Not valid on federal holidays. Reservation required.'
```

Comment: The problem here is that is needs to be constrained within the same sentence (bounded by a period), the date specifications can be either before or after the term brunch and other words can be between the date specifier and 'brunch'.

Comment: ok if you can update your question with additional examples then I will tweak this this regex.

Answer (score 0):

You are not forced to use `regex` for all , you can split your sentence and process each of them separately and use a list comprehension instead  :

```
>>> import re
>>> l=s.split('.')
>>> print '.'.join([re.sub('brunch','BRUNCH',sent) if 'Saturday' in sent or 'Sunday' in sent or 'Weekend' in sent else sent for sent in l])
'Limit 1 per person. Limit 1 per table. Not valid for carryout. Not valid 
    with any other offers, no cash back. Valid only for Wednesday-Friday dinner and 
    Saturday-Sunday BRUNCH. Not valid on federal holidays. Reservation required.'
```